# SQL Server How to insert current results into table

Tags: sql-server

I have just run a very lengthy query for which the results are very useful.

Unfortunately I did not insert the results into a table, they are only displayed in the results view is there any way to store the current results table into a temp table? The data obviously exists.. Is something possible like:

```
SELECT * INTO #tempresults FROM CurrentResults
```

Where currentresults points to... current results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to save that results as tab separated file. To do that click in the little blank square on top left of the results. This will select all results you see. After that do right click on the same little square and select **Copy with Headers**.

[image]

This will copy all results in the clipboard using tabs as columns delimiter and new line symbol (\r\n) as rows delimiter. Paste it to the new file. Now you can use **Import Data** menu to insert your results in the table (new one or existing one):

[image]

Select **Flat File Source** as Data Source in Import Wizard, choose the file you made. Be sure to set a proper **DataType** for each column you importing in **Advanced** menu on the left. Otherwise you will get some errors/warnings during import:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your only option now is to right-click on Grid, pick "Save Results As ..." and export the data to CSV file.

Comment: Okay thanks Adam, its a shame there isn't a method to recall the results into a table, but beggars can't be choosers